Unable to understand CDATA usage in CKEDitor
Can someone explain what is the purpose of CDATA in CKEditor?
When we have to use CDATA?
Please can someone provide a real time example?
My Example is
This is very specific to CKEditor.
<html>
<head>
<title>CDATA Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cdataExample">
<![CDATA[This is something inside cdata <b>this is bold</b>]] >
</div>
</body>
</html>

But this is not working....
I checked the code...
After setting the above content into an element, the editor reads the content from the same element...That time the content is completely corrupted like the below...
<![CDATA[This is something inside cdata <b--->this is bold</b>]] >

Can you please help me to understand in detail about CDATA? Why it is used in CKEDitor? How to resolve the above problem?

This question is similar to: What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
